# D3 graph shows zero in y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

Hello i was plotting D3 line  graph  with brush and zoom

i was able to do it but in y-axis of the graph the values shows zero even after data having some values

and one more problem is  mouse-hover even is not firing properly  on circles  due to `pointer-events: all;` on .zoom class

adding fiddle  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/manju123/urgcgd03/)

Answer (score 0):

Set margin left more, 60 instead 20  and you will be happy:)

```
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 60},
```

Comment: thanks a lot 

can you help me on mouse-hover part ??  

if i hover on circle wont turn to pointer there is some think to do with css which i'm not able to figure out

Comment: can you describe problem detail?)) you need other type of cursor?)

Comment: can you please check the Fidel now  hover is not working on circle 
 
i have increased the volume of data

if i remove     /* pointer-events: all; */ css attribute from .zoom class hover works fine but zooming wont work 

it will be great work

Comment: i'm sorry my Fidel was not updated can you please check here https://jsfiddle.net/manju123/urgcgd03/3/